# It does not work concatenation in function.php

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

I want to put a variable between two tags, but it puts him out.

This is my function: (function.php)

```
/* traer thumb */
function item_thumb() {
  global $post;

  if (has_post_format('video')) {

    $key_1_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video', true );

    if (!empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
      $post_video = '<div class="item-video embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">';               
      $post_video.= wp_oembed_get($key_1_value);
      $post_video.= '</div>';

      return $post_video;
    }

  } else { 

    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {

      $item_image = '<div class="item-image">';
      $item_image.= the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb_destacado', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive full-width'));
      $item_image.= '</div>';

      return $item_image;
    }
  }
}
```

And get this:
The video are okay:

```
<div class="item-video embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe width="600" height="338" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rdlFMPXJ44o?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
</div>
```

But the thumbnails appears so:

```
<img width="630" height="300" src="http://localhost/agroverdad.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Carne-Exportacion-630-630x300.jpg" class="img-responsive full-width wp-post-image" alt="Carne-Exportacion-630">
<div class="item-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail()` echoes data immediate, what you want to try is `get_the_post_thumbnail()` which returns data so that you may concatenate properly.

WordPress core functions that are prefixed with `the_` usually echo, those prefixed with `get_` usually return.

See:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Thanks, I changed `the_` to `get_` and I had to add the parameter `$post-> ID`. Now it works perfect

Comment: Ah yes, if you are outside the loop or the default `global $post` object is not present in scope then you need to supply an ID or an instance of `WP_Post`. Glad it is working for you...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using [the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) instead of [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/).

In general in WP, anything starting with `the_` will output data and anything starting with `get_` will return data.